# Variable Declaration Methods

Tags: c++, variables

I can guess this is a newbie question but I seemed to have missed it somewhere, plus I am a newbie so if the answer is obvious don't be too mean...

I have seen variables declared multiple ways:

```
DataType varName = value;
DataType varName(value);
DataType varName{value};
```

I thought it was one of those writers choice situations, but recently I was trying to add 2 char variables and set it to another char variable and I used the braces version:

```
unsigned char sum{ char1 + char2 };
```

And I get an error:
Error   1   error C2398: Element '1': conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char &' requires a narrowing conversion.

But I don't get that error with:

```
unsigned char sum(char1 + char2);
```

So can someone please explain the difference between the declarations or provide a link to a site that will?

Thanks...

Comment: Using braces prevents narrowing conversions. It also gets more complicated when dealing with non-built-in types.

Comment: A very good discussion of this can be found at http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: When you add two `char`s, you get an `int`, and brace initialization intentionally disallows such assignments.

C++, in keeping with C, performs integer promotion for addition; because of this, the type of the expression `char1 + char2` (assuming `char1` and `char2` are both of type `char`) is not `char` as one might expect, but is instead `int`. The relevant sections of the standard are §4.5 (which describes integral *promotions*), §4.13 (integral *conversions*), and §5.7 (additive operators, which induce integral promotion).

As for why this causes the statement `unsigned char sum {char1 + char2};` to fail, brace initialization is specifically designed to help prevent the programmer from performing narrowing conversions (§8.5.3), which may cause overflow. Because `int` is at least twice the size of `char` (on an octet-addressable machine*), this is a narrowing conversion, and so fails.

Of course, in the end, you might want to stop and ask yourself, "What exactly does it mean to add two characters, anyway?"

---

*For the interested, C++ says that `int` is large enough to hold at least the values `INT_MIN` through `INT_MAX` (§3.9.2) and delegates the definitions of those macros to C (§18.3.3.2), which gives them (Annex E, §1) minimum values of -32767 and +32767, respectively**. Thus, `int` requires at least sixteen bits. `char`, on the other hand, is a minimum of eight bits wide. C also defines `char` as being one byte wide (§6.2.5.3, §5.2.1), where a byte (§3.6) is an "addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment." Strictly speaking, I think `char` could by this definition be *larger* than one byte, but I'm pretty sure it cannot be wider than any other type.

**That's -32767, not -32768. C notably doesn't actually impose two's-complement representation of signed integers on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example can't be used if `value` is not a `DataType` and that ctor is writen as `explicit`.  The second will try to call a ctor with parameter `value`, but will work if it's `explicit`. The third, with braces, prevents narrowing conversions.

Comment: The first doesn't work if the constructor of `DataType` is `explicit`.

Comment: @chris Correct, just made that change to the answer